# Excel VBA - How can I send email with text specific to certain cell values?

Tags: excel, vba, email, ref

Currently working on an order form in Excel and I'm stuck on sending an email via macro button.

Now I've seen online plenty of "how to send email using VBA in Excel" and I understand what they're on about.

My problem is I want the email body to display not only the main body of the email but I want to be able to put in a random numerical value a cell and the macro picks this up and dumps this cell value along with text specific to that cell.

For example the ordering form has 4 circuit boards I can order. For now these will be Represent by A, B, C & D

If I put 100 in each circuit board's quantity cell and click the Order button.

The following email would be as follows:

```
Dear <Name>

I'd like to order 100 of A, 100 of B, 100 of C & 100 of D

Kind Regards,

<Name>
```

Meanwhile if suddenly in the next order I want to place, I put only 20 in A & 60 in C, the email will change to reflect this change:

```
Dear <Name>

I'd like to order 20 of A & 60 of C

Kind Regards,

<Name>
```

These changes being the placement of comma's, fullstops and the et symbol '&'.

Anyone able to point me in the general direction of how I can do this/adapt current tutorials to get the result I require?

Edit: Seems there's a little misunderstanding in the form I'm on about so here's the current setup:
[image]

What I want to achieve via pressing the order button:
Takes cell values from the amount column that corresponds to each individual board in the type column.

And takes those values into the main body of the email.
In regards to the specific text such as commas etc. I was thinking more like a if statement format e.g. if B3 has value && B4 has a value but B5 and B6 == 0 then post in email body (B3)"(ref no)"+" & " + (B4)"(ref no)"

And so forth based whether or not any of those cells has a value in it.
I'm not asking for text to be placed in other cells either such as cell J7 containing "I would like" etc.. that type of text I'll add directly onto the VBA script.

@BBRK - As regards to my comment on your answer this is what I mean by changing the message body:

```
  xMailBody = "Hi <NAME>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "I'd like to order" & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards"
                  On Error Resume Next
```

This code shows up as the following:
[image]

Realistically I wish to change the text being reference in Column A and replace that with hard-coded reference number which will correspond to orders I've made with the supplier.

Also I wish to change the positioning of the "0 of Vibro" and move that to after I've said I would like to order but not show up on the next line where it current is next to the "Kind Regards," section.

@BBRK here is current full VBA:

```
Private Sub Board_Order()

    Dim xMailBody As String
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim count_var As Integer
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim arr_val() As Integer
    Dim great_count As Integer
    Dim arr_now As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

    arr_now = 0

    'Gets the count of number of zeroes available in the B3 to last data filled row of that column.
    great_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B3:B6" & Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row), ">0")

    xMailBody = "Hi <NAME>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "I'd like to order" & vbNewLine & _
                "Kind Regards"
                    On Error Resume Next

    'If orders are there then will go for further processing.
    If great_count <> 0 Then

        'Resizes array according to the count
        ReDim arr(0 To great_count - 1)
        ReDim arr_val(0 To great_count - 1)

        'Loops through the range and input product into the arr and it's value in arr_val
        If great_count > 0 Then
            For i = 3 To Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row
                If Range("B" & i).Value > 0 Then
                    arr(arr_now) = Range("A" & i).Value
                    arr_val(arr_now) = Range("B" & i).Value
                    arr_now = arr_now + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If

        'Looping through each element in the array to get the desired result.
            If great_count = 1 Then
                xMailBody = xMailBody + " " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
            Else
                For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If j = 0 Then
                        xMailBody = xMailBody + " " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                    ElseIf j = UBound(arr) Then
                        xMailBody = xMailBody + " & " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                    Else
                        xMailBody = xMailBody + " , " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
    End If

    With xOutMail
            .To = "marcbrooks991@hotmail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Test email send by button clicking"
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: There are lot of things that you need to consider. `1` what to do if the qty cells are empty? `2` How many items are there that can be ordered? `3` you have a set range then looping through the range and concatenating values based on what you have in qty field will help.

Comment: Ideally if your items list can increase then arranging them vertically will help. `Items` in `Col A` and `Qty` in `Col B`. That way you can loop through each item in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation, I have developed a VBA method in Excel.

This will help you out to generate the concatenated string you want.

Copy and Paste below Excel VBA code in the editor and try to run it.

```
Sub Generate_String()
Dim HTML_body As String
Dim count_var As Integer
Dim arr() As String
Dim arr_val() As Integer
Dim great_count As Integer
Dim arr_now As Integer
Dim xMailBody As String
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object

Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

arr_now = 0

'Gets the count of number of zeroes available in the B3 to last data filled row of that column.
great_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B3:B" & Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row), ">0")

HTML_body = "Hi <Name>," & vbnewline & vbnewline & "I'd like to order"

'If orders are there then will go for further processing.
If great_count <> 0 Then

    'Resizes array according to the count
    ReDim arr(0 To great_count - 1)
    ReDim arr_val(0 To great_count - 1)

    'Loops through the range and input product into the arr and it's value in arr_val
    If great_count > 0 Then
        For i = 3 To Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row
            If Range("B" & i).Value > 0 Then
                arr(arr_now) = Range("A" & i).Value
                arr_val(arr_now) = Range("B" & i).Value
                arr_now = arr_now + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    'Looping through each element in the array to get the desired result.
        If great_count = 1 Then
            HTML_body = HTML_body + " " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
        Else
            For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                If j = 0 Then
                    HTML_body = HTML_body + " " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                ElseIf j = UBound(arr) Then
                    HTML_body = HTML_body + " & " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                Else
                    HTML_body = HTML_body + " , " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                End If
            Next j
        End If
Else
    HTML_body = "No Orders"
End If

HTML_body = HTML_body & vbnewline & "Kind Regards" & vbnewline & "<Name>"
With xOutMail
        .To = "marcbrooks991@hotmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test email send by button clicking"
        .Body = HTML_body
        .Display   'or use .Send
End With
End Sub
```

Modify it as per your need.
Hope I was able to help you out.

I have edited the code as per your need. Problem was that you were adding 'Kind Regards' text before your processing.

**EDIT2:**

With validation checks if the amount column for any row is blank

```
Sub Generate_String()
Dim HTML_body As String
Dim count_var As Integer
Dim arr() As String
Dim arr_val() As Integer
Dim great_count As Integer
Dim arr_now As Integer
Dim rng_Body As Range
Dim xMailBody As String
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim validate_pass As Boolean

'Checks if the any of the range has blank values
'if blank value is found it will make validate_pass variable to false.
Set rng_Body = Range("B3:B" & Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row)
validate_pass = True
For Each r In rng_Body
    If Trim(r.Text) = "" Then
        validate_pass = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next r

'If validate_pass variable is false then throws out error message.
'Else it will go through the normal procedure to sent out emails.
If validate_pass = False Then
    MsgBox "Your appropriate error message if any of the amount value found blank", vbCritical
Else
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

    arr_now = 0

    Set rng_Body = Range("B3:B" & Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row)


    'Gets the count of number of zeroes available in the B3 to last data filled row of that column.
    great_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B3:B" & Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row), ">0")

    HTML_body = "Hi <Name>," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "I'd like to order"

    'If orders are there then will go for further processing.
    If great_count <> 0 Then

        'Resizes array according to the count
        ReDim arr(0 To great_count - 1)
        ReDim arr_val(0 To great_count - 1)

        'Loops through the range and input product into the arr and it's value in arr_val
        If great_count > 0 Then
            For i = 3 To Range("B3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row
                If Range("B" & i).Value > 0 Then
                    arr(arr_now) = Range("A" & i).Value
                    arr_val(arr_now) = Range("B" & i).Value
                    arr_now = arr_now + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If

        'Looping through each element in the array to get the desired result.
            If great_count = 1 Then
                HTML_body = HTML_body + " " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
            Else
                For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If j = 0 Then
                        HTML_body = HTML_body + " " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                    ElseIf j = UBound(arr) Then
                        HTML_body = HTML_body + " & " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                    Else
                        HTML_body = HTML_body + " , " + CStr(arr_val(j)) + " of " + arr(j)
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
    Else
        HTML_body = "No Orders"
    End If

    HTML_body = HTML_body & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & "<Name>"
    With xOutMail
            .To = "marcbrooks991@hotmail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Test email send by button clicking"
            .Body = HTML_body
            .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    MsgBox "Order Email has been Sent"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers that works out great. Curious question, how do you change the text that mentions the type? As I need to change that to a set of reference numbers instead of it referring to cells in column A.

Also how do I go about changing the body of the message?
I'll post an edit showing what I mean.

Comment: Can you post your whole VBA code for the reference ? Need to see what you have created.

Comment: Are you using Outlook for generating mails ?

Comment: Yes I am, using outlook for generating the mails.

Comment: So what will be the <Name> in the email ?

Comment: I plan to use the vba code on multiple ordering buttons. So I have the <NAME> as a placeholder for the supplier that I'm going to be contacting, followed by <NAME> at bottom as placeholder for my name plus signature etc..

Comment: Forgot to add also need to find out how to add in a validation check so if no value has been placed in the amount field. Want it to bring up msgbox stating to input a value into the amount box.

Likewise when message is sent a msgbox would show up saying "Order Email has been Sent" etc but I'm sure I can figure that stuff out.

Comment: ^ Added in the validation check for quantity now, just need to figure out the placement of the text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181916/discussion-between-bbrk-and-marc-brooks).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can combine text and numbers together to get what you want as so:

```
=A1&" "&A2&" "&A3
```

Where
cell A1 contains "I would like"
cell A2 contains the value 100
cell A3 contains "variable resistors"

which results in:
I would like 100 variable resistors